# Django: get_queryset method for a Search View to filter with multiple fields

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I am working on an HTML form to filter multiple model fields.

### Question:

How to build the view so a single queryset is returned even with changing queries?

### HTML

My form will pass the inputs as kwargs so request will be like this -

```
/search/?order_by=newest
/search/?q=<string>&order_by=newest
/search/?q=<string>&order_by=newest&country=US
```

These would filter upon:

- The `string` in query (q=...)
- The `order_by` to order the queryset
- The `country` to filter the results by a location field

### View:

I'm trying to have a single query in the view to remove complexity and keep the view as simple as possible. How can I take all of these potential variations and pass through a single `get_queryset` method?

Here is what I have right now.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    keywords = self.request.GET.get('q') or None
    order_by = self.order_by_options.get(
        self.request.GET.get('order_by')) or '-date_of_price'
    if keywords:
        query = SearchQuery(keywords)
        vectors = SearchVector('name', weight='A')
        qs = self.model.objects_for_search.annotate(search=vectors).filter(
            search=query).order_by('sold', order_by, '-modified')
    else:
        qs = self.model.objects_for_search.order_by('sold', order_by, '-modified')
    return qs[0:500]
```

The issue with the code above is that the more attributes I add, the more `if statements`. This code has the `if statement` for keywords, and that doesn't feel elegant/pythonic to me. Adding another `if statement` for the country query would definitely be odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kwargs = {
    'q': request.GET.get('q',''),
    'order_by_field': request.GET.get('order_by','-date_of_price'),
    'country': request.GET.get('country','-date_of_price')
}
```

Get all query parameter  and make a kwargs with these. we don't have options other than if else. For eg -

```
    filter_kwargs = {}
    if 'q' in kwargs and kwargs['q']:
        filter_kwargs['keyword'] = kwargs['q']
    if 'country' in kwargs and kwargs['country']:
        filter_kwargs['country'] = kwargs['country']

    result = self.query.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs) \
             .order_by(kwargs['order_by_field'])
```